# Abstraction for player, NPC's, and monsters

Tags: unity, character, npc, single-player

I am trying to come up with a good abstract term for my players, NPC's and monsters. They can all have stats and inventory. so they all can function in the same way. But some could be humanoids, some are monsters and whatnot. Are there any standard abstract terms that game devs tend to use.

Comment: Actor, Entity, Mob(mobile) are some that I've used. But each game will call them different things, unless there's a specific framework you're using (Godot, unity, libgdx).

Comment: Those are good. I also thought about agent.